# mv with wildcard fails with "No such file or directory" if no files match wildcard

Tags: bash, mv

I am running the following command:

```
mv logs/*.log logs/bak/
```

Now, when my logs folder contains a file which matches `*.log`, it works fine.

However, in case of no matching file, it throws error

```
mv: cannot stat 'logs/*.log': No such file or directory
```

How can I make this work?

**EDIT**
I am trying to make this exit with a zero status code without doing anything so that I can use this in my build process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` instead of `mv`:

For example:

```sh
find logs -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv '{}' logs/bak  \;
```

... and while you are experimenting with this command, preface it with `echo` and/or use verbose:

```sh
find logs -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo mv '{}' logs/bak  \;
```

```sh
find logs -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -v '{}' logs/bak  \;
```

Note the options:

`-maxdepth 1` : prevent recursion into sub directories

`-type f` : only consider regular files

To match only files ending in `.log` you can add option:

`-name *.log`

**EDIT BY OP**

So, the final command comes out to be:

```
find logs -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.log -exec mv -v '{}' logs/bak  \;
```

Comment: You final command is flawed. It will fail if you run it as is and there are no files. You must quote the `"*.log"`, otherwise it will expand to nothing and the find parameters will be messed up.

Comment: I dont think it fails.   Please post an example.  If that above command is run as-is, even on an empty directory, it still works.

Comment: @Poshi I just ran it and it works fine for both cases, empty and existing

Comment: Although general point, the quotes should be added as @Poshi advises, or escape the asterisk,  as in:  `\*.log`.

Comment: If it works when there are no files... I will be really surprised and I won't be able to explain why it works. But if it fits your needs, good to go! Anyways, as a general recomendation, always quote your strings and your variables.